# extract values from a text file with awk

Tags: awk

I would like to extract  column1 from the text files based on the values of column2. I need to print column1 only if the column2 is greater than 20.I also need to print the name of the file with the output. How can I do this with awk?

```
file1.txt 

alias    23
samson   10
george   24

file2.txt 

andrew   12
susan    16
david    25   

desired output

file1

alias
george

file2

david
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
awk '$2>20{print $1}' file1 file2
```

if you want file names and prettier printing:

```
awk 'FNR==1{print FILENAME} $2>20{print "    ",$1}' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk '{ if($2 > 20) { print FILENAME " " $1 } }' <files>`

Comment: Better yet, remove that "if" and the outer pair of braces.

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff Thank you for your answer. File names are not printed with the output.Instead of that, the content of files is printing.

Comment: Oh sorry, that's a typo -- it should be just FILENAME without the $. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$2>20{if(file!=FILENAME){print FILENAME;file=FILENAME}print}' file1 file2
```

see below:

```
> awk '$2>20{if(file!=FILENAME){print FILENAME;file=FILENAME}print}' file1 file2
file1
    alias    23
    george   24
file2
    david    25
```